# Geopandas map layering

Tags: python, geopandas

I am learning to create 'layered' maps in Spyder IDE with geopandas package with using this code:

```
import geopandas as geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

world.plot()

ax = plt.subplot(1, 1)
world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

I execute code line by line as in RStudio.
Unfortunately, I am only able to obtain a white blank sheet instead of a map.

Comment: Could you share an image of your output ? What do you want exactly ? The same thing as in the `geopandas` doc ?

Comment: @linog, yes, that is exactly what I am trying to replicate.

Comment: Did my answer helped or did I missed the point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the example on `Jupyter` but I don't think it should change anything as long as you have the packages installed.

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))
world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

[image]

If you are only interested in the geometry, you can do the following:

```py
world.geometry.plot(color="white", edgecolor='k')
```

If, in the future, you want to add this geometry to a map, you can do

```py
world.geometry.plot(color=None, edgecolor='k')
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you, code works in both Jupiter and Spyder!